# Relative links in MS Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, copy-paste, links

I'm trying to include some Excel data in a Word document. To do this, I copy the cell from Excel, and do a Paste->Paste Special->Paste Link in Word, and choose HTML format. The problem is, this causes the link to be absolute, and breaks when I give someone a copy. I'd like for these links to be relative - is this possible?

Comment: Apparently, the answer is no, or at least no unless you are willing to and are knowledgeable enough to make changes inside the underlying document structure.  See [this link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/officesetupdeployprevious/thread/6d4445e1-cdc5-4b3b-9355-9081c963fdd9) for a discussion of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you embed a word document (must be a 97-2003 Document) inside of your excel file (I usually link it as an icon and then double click the icon to edit the linked word document), you can then use the paste special link within the embedded word file and linked content from your excel file will be relative to your excel file. Furthermore if you do a saveas of your embedded word file it will remain relative to the excel file from which you did the saveas from. This has been an effective way for me to link content relative to the excel file.